# Dotnet build don't stop in docker build command in bitbucket

Tags: .net, docker, bitbucket, .net-6.0, bitbucket-pipelines

I've got a docker task in a bitbucket pipeline that's running in a loop, or at least taking much longer than usual. It's going to the end of the 2h maximum time limit for bicbucket pipelines. In the logs, it's the "dotnet build" command that doesn't seem to finish.

I've tried to put the command in question in the diagnostic log with the "-v diag" option, but all I get is the last command, which is "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet exec "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.415/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll" " with all the solution's references and .cs files as parameters. As you can see I use .net6.0

I just tried to update all my packages to 6.0.23 (I was in 6.0.17) but it didn't change anything.

Locally the solution build without any problem.